# Get current post type within functions.php

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, ajax

In my function.php I need to run something to check post type or page id.

how can i check current post type loaded in functions.php

**function.php**

```
  <?php
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');



function filterPosts()
{
    
     global $post;

    if( is_singular() ) {
        if( 'post_type_b' == $post->post_type ) {
           $certain_post='post_b';
        } elseif ( 'post' == $post->post_type ) {
             $certain_post='post';
        }
    }
    
    
    $response = [
        'posts' => "",
    ];
    
     // New args for an All Posts Query
    $all_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // returns all posts
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => $certain_post
        );

    $filter_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => $certain_post
    );

    if ($_POST['limit']) {
        $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['limit'];
    }

    if ($_POST['category']) {
        $filter_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
        
         // Get the total number of posts for the category
        $all_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
    }

    $filter_query = new WP_Query($filter_args);
    
    // New All Posts Query
    $all_query = new WP_Query($all_args);

    if ($filter_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($filter_query->have_posts()) : $filter_query->the_post();
            $response['posts'] .= load_template_part('/template-parts/posts-filter/single-post');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

Comment: An AJAX handler doesn't know which page requested it so functions like `is_singular` or using global variables don't make sense, the only way it can know is if you pass it from javascript in the request and read it in a GET variable. The same for anything else about the page that made the AJAX request. Remember, each request to the server starts with a fresh blank slate, no variables survive once the request is finished. If you want things to carry over you got to save them somewhere, DB/Cookie/files/etc/etc, there's no persistent long running web program like in NodeJS/Java

Comment: @TomJNowell dam, seems im screwed. been following this tutorial but now want to make the filtered post depending on what post im on. https://joeyfarruggio.com/wordpress/posts-category-filter/#connecting-category-buttons-to-alpine

Comment: there anyway to get something i can write a statement from, even current url ?

Comment: the article you've linked to doesn't contain any of the mistakes I mentioned, an AJAX handler doesn't know who or what has called it, it only knows what it has been given. If it needs to know if the page calling it is `is_singular() === true` then it can't find that out on its own, just like you followed the tutorial and grabbed the category and sent it to the AJAX handler via `POST` _if you want it to know which page its on or the post type then it has to be told and passed that information hint hint_

Comment: likewise it can't find out the URL on its own, that can't be done from the PHP side _but it can be done on the javascript side and passed along_

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, found a solution and will update later